# Django model OneToOneField : "This field is required" error in admin

Tags: python, django, model, django-admin

When I open an entry of "Placerating" in Admin, and try to save it after making a change to any field, Django admin displays "This field is required" above the field "Pic".

```
class Placerating(models.Model):
    theplace = models.ForeignKey('ThePlace', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='placeratings')
    pic = models.OneToOneField('fileupload.Picture', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.theplace.name

class Picture(models.Model):
    def set_upload_to_info(self, path, name):
        self.upload_to_info = (path, name)
    file = ImageField(max_length=500, upload_to=user_directory_path)
    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.file.name)
    theplace = models.ForeignKey(ThePlace, null=True, blank=True, related_name='pictures')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Picture, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I created the entry without problem with a form, so I don't understand why admin would now require this field to be completed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.null) about the `null` argument to model fields:

> For both string-based and non-string-based fields, you will also need
>   to set blank=True if you wish to permit empty values in forms, as the
>   [null](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.null) parameter only affects database storage (see [blank](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.blank)).

The admin uses forms for creation and editing, so you need `blank=True` in the fields you want to be able to leave blank in the admin.